# How do the same random value in second coordinate in line in QGIS?

Tags: python, random, coordinates

It is my first tag here, I don't know how to create a random(). To make the same two coordinates with B and B1

For example

First line in virtual layer - A, B,

Second line in virtual layer - B1, C

I want do something in Python but I don't know what. I tried random.uniform
and random.setstate, but I don't know how I can do that B and B1 have the same coordinate?

Help me:)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any issue with simply having B = B1? Should be as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

I think that random.seed gave me what i want :)